# Neighbor is being scammed by an online romance scam - What can I do?

Tags: scams

I hope this is the correct forum for this query. Anyhow, I have a next door neighbor who is currently being scammed. I know this because the person scamming her is passing himself off as Johnny Depp (his messenger and hangouts profile shows the real JD picture and a gmail address with the name Johnny Depp). This scammer has milked her out of many thousands of dollars over just one year. Now herein lies the problem: She actually will not be convinced of even the slightest possibility that this person is fake (even though he keeps asking and getting off her things like itunes cards and gift vouchers and cash). Now first I don't know how to convince her this is a scam, second of all, I'm worried what she may do to herself if she did come to realize this (in one of her messages to JD fake I 'accidentally' saw, she states that 'I would literally die if anything happened to you or if you were not in my life anymore'. I think there may be a small amount of truth to that as she suffers from depression. I dont know what to do. And now this person is asking her to receive money from him whereby she would then transfer these funds to 'orphanages'. So I think the scammer is now introducing her to money laundering. What do I do? Obviously I dont want her doing jail time.

Comment: You need to sit down and have an intervention with your friend. Tell her why would the real JD ask her to buy iTunes  GCs? I doubt the police can do much.

Comment: This is undoubtedly a sad situation, but your guess is right - this isn't the correct forum. It sounds like a matter for local law enforcement.

Comment: The title of your question says "romance" even though it isn't mentioned in the post. But if she is in fact in love with him, you might be able to convince her to stop all financial transactions until after she meets JD in person. (After all she's done for him, it's the least he can do.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about personal finance, it's a legal or interpersonal relationships question.

Comment: JD has had a lot of financial problems lately, maybe it really is him.

Comment: Since this is not a question about _rational_ handling of money, you might want to ask at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com which I think is a lot more suitable.

Comment: Love ( infatuation? ) is blind.... and often stupid.

Answer (score 10):

It is nice that you care for this person to take the time to post this and worry about their future.  However, the relationship of "neighbor" means little in these situations.  If I was in your shoes, I would do two things:

The first would be to contact law enforcement.  However, I doubt that will get very far.

The second would be to engage this woman's family and describe the situation.  Perhaps they can get through to her or possibly declare her mentally incompetent to manage her own affairs.

Comment: I concur with the second point. I'd consider this a 'drunk and the bar' situation. Their family needs to have an 'intervention'. It's clear there is an issue, the catfisher won't relent, and the victim is (probably) actively being ignorant about this issue.

Comment: +1 for contact the family.  Not only is she more likely to listen to her family than her neighbour (no offense,) but this is a situation they ought to be aware of.  She may not be your neighbour forever, but she will be their family.